# Can I get WCF to run on VS Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

Is it possible to get WCF to run under Express edition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  Are you finding otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Which Express edition are you running?

Visual C# 2008 Express doesn't have the WCF templates on New Project but Visual Web Developer 2008 Express does.

Answer (score 0):

also VS express doesn't have tool for editing service configuration, which I think is very helpful for WCF newbies (like me :)

Comment: If you have the Windows SDK installed, you'll find several useful WCF-related tools in \Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin. SvcConfigEditor.exe in particular will help with the above.

Comment: True, but I like having everything needed in IDE. I know I could configure it as external tool but it's not the same, you know... :)